# How to calculate the torque produced by a spool rotating in a uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Assume a setup where you know the radius $R$ of a conductive loop that has $N$ windings, which is rotating at a frequency of $\omega$. Suppose you also know its length and resistance. Then, you could calculate the inductive voltage through Lenz's Law, and calculate the current through $I = U/R$. Now, I want to calculate the torque that this generates on the loop. I suppose you would calculate the Lorentz Force using $\displaystyle \mathbf {F} =I\int \mathrm {d} {\boldsymbol {\ell }}\times \mathbf {B}$ . I need help parametizing $\vec{dl}$. I find it difficult because the circle that you want to parametize is also rotating in the plane, which I think would make it dependent on $d\phi$ and $t$ aswell. Any help would be appreciated!
Also, I am clueless about how to calculate the torque out of the Force. would you integrate it over the whole circle?
[image]

Comment: a sketch of the system would help

Answer (score 0):

Approximating the geometry of a N-winding loop as the union of $N$ loops, it's quite easy to find the result you need.

The formula to evaluate the moment becomes
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{M} = \int_{\ell} \mathbf{r} \times d \mathbf{F} \sim N \oint_C \mathbf{r} \times d \mathbf{F}  = - N i \oint_{C} \mathbf{r} \times \left[ \mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{\hat{t}} \right] =: - N i \mathbf{I} \ .
\end{equation}

It's possible to evaluate the integral $\mathbf{I}$ using integration by parts, with the assumption of uniform $\mathbf{B}$ to get
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{I} = \oint_C \mathbf{r} \times \left[ \mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{\hat{t}}\right]  = \dots = - \int_{S} \mathbf{\hat{n}} \times \mathbf{B} \ .
\end{equation}

Now, assuming the magnetic field to be $\mathbf{B} = B \mathbf{\hat{x}}$ and the unit normal $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{\hat{X}}$ along the axis of the N-winding loop, so that the angles between these two vectors is $\theta$, the integral become
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{I} = A \, B \sin \theta \mathbf{\hat{z}} \ ,
\end{equation}
being $A$ the area of the sections of the loop, and $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ the axis of rotation. The moment eventually is
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{M} = - N \, i \, A \, B \sin\theta \mathbf{\hat{z}} \ .
\end{equation}

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of something more like the calculation I attached just now, I perhaps didn't explain my setup clearly enough. May I ask why you have no time dependencies in your calculations?

Comment: You have time dependency it the loops rotate in the angle $\theta(t)$, and if the current is not constant $i(t)$. While it's reasonable to assume constant number of loops $N$, constant section $A$, and constant magnetic field $B$